# Download page as JSON in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I have a view which returns a formatted JSON object. It takes a list of words (labeled "forms" and "lemmas" for this project), formats them into a nice dictionary object and outputs a json page which can then be saved by the user.

`views.py`

```
def search_view(request):
    """
    The app revolves around this view, which is also the homepage.
    """
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'search.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        checked_A = {}
        checked_B = {}

        # All lemma keys are of the form {lemma}@{group}.
        # All form keys are of the form {lemma}@{group}@{form}.
        # The "@" symbol will not appear in any other key.
        # Split the key_data into two parts, the lemma/group part
        # and the form part. The form part is either [] or [form]

        for key in request.POST:
            if "@" not in key:
                continue
            key_data = key.split("@")
            (lemma, group), form = key_data[:2], key_data[2:]
            if group == "A":
                if checked_A.get(lemma):
                    checked_A[lemma].extend(form)
                else:
                    checked_A[lemma] = list(form)
            if group == "B":
                if checked_B.get(lemma):
                    checked_B[lemma].extend(form)
                else:
                    checked_B[lemma] = list(form)

        context['query_A'] = checked_A
        context['query_B'] = checked_B

        return JsonResponse(context, status=200) # <-- the only important part
```

Is there a way to create a button which will download this data directly, instead of having the user go to a separate page and save the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you must simply add an additional header to the http response object, specifically a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.

See the details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Thanks! Trying it now.